# Two subspaces are Homeomorphic in $\mathbb R^2$ with box topology

Tags: general-topology

Show that $K = \{(x \times y) \in \mathbb R^2 \ \ | \ \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1] \times [0,1] $, where $[0,1]$ is closed interval in $\mathbb R$

I have tried

Define a function $f$

$f(r ,\theta) = (r \cos \theta  , r \sin \theta ) = (f_1( r , \theta) , f_2(r , \theta ))  $ , where $f_1(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta$ and $f_2(r,\theta) = r\sin \theta$.

Since $\tau $ is a box topology and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continous. So $f$ is contnous.

we need to Show that $f$ is an open and bijective . I am unable to Show that $f$ is bijective and open .

Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: I don't see a definition of a function yet. Which way is your $f$ supposed to go? From $K\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$ or the other way? Apparently $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates, but then what is $r\cos\theta\times r\sin\theta$? What does that $\times$ stand for? Cannot be the cross product, because it is applied to scalars. Cannot be the product of scalars, because $r\times\theta$ should either be a point of $K$ or a point of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. So what does it mean? What are your $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: Is it possible that some textbook somewhere uses the notation $a\times b$ for the ordered pair $(a,b)$?

Comment: showing homeomorphism between $K$ and $[-1,1]$x$[-1,1]$ should be easier

Comment: @ Jyrki : $ (a \times b)$ denotes the orddered pair $(a,b)$ in the cartesian product $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @ Tanuj : You are right , it may be bijective

Comment: @ Tanuj : @ if we take $ f : K \rightarrow [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ , then $f$ is not an onto, because inverse image of inverse image is $(r,\theta )$, where $r = \sqrt{2}$ and $\theta  = \tan^{-1} (y/x)$ which is not in $K$

Comment: @ Jyrki : $f_1 (r,\theta ) = r\cos \theta,$ and $f_2( r, \theta) = r \sin \theta $

Comment: f(0,x)=f(0,y).. when x ,y not equal........................The use of aXb for an ordered pair is not standard. It is usually (a,b) or <a,b>.

Comment: ok i am editting

Comment: @User 254665:  any other function in your mind which give a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Map K to the closed disc  D of radius 1/2 ,centered at (1/2,1/2)=C. For each point P on the boundary of D, let P' be the closest point, on the boundary of the square [0,1]X[0,1],that also lies on the line thru C and P. Map the segment CP linearly to CP' with f(C)=C and f(P)=P'.It helps to draw a picture.

Comment: I think , You have defined a function $f : D \rightarrow [0,1]  \times [0,1]$ such that any point $x \in D$ , draw a line passes through x and $C$  meet at $P$ on the boundary of the disc and choose a closest point on the boundary of  the square says $P'$ and proceed like this, I will  try that this prove $D$ is homeomorphic to the square. Am I right

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.If the ratio  CP/CP' =r, and  x is on CP,then f(x) is on CP' with Cx/Cf(x)=r.

Comment: @ user254665 : Continuity of $f$ ; Now by Triangular Inequality  $d ( f(x,y) , f(a,b) ) \leq d(f(x,y) , (1/2 , 1/2) ) + d( f(a,b) , (1/2 ,1/2) )$  $= \frac{d ((x,y) , (1/2 , 1/2) ) }{r_1} + \frac{d((a,b) , (1/2,1/2) ) }{r_2}$, where $d$ is the Euvlidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$ and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the raio as you have defined. Please tell me how to proceed further